# Inhibit Variable Expansion in Paths

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables, path, autocomplete

How do I prevent Zshell (and Bash I assume) from expanding environment variables in paths be completed as shown in the following example:

```
$PREFIX/alt/li
```

should expand to

```
$PREFIX/alt/lib
```

and not to say

```
/opt/alt/lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior under zsh. The `complete-word` and `expand-or-complete` [zle widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Completion) don't expand parameters whose value is a directory name, as long as there's a `/` after it (i.e. `$foo/<TAB>`).

There are many ways to customize this behavior. For example, maybe you've set up <kbd>Tab</kbd> to run `expand-or-complete-prefix`. There are also [styles](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles) such as `expand` and `keep-prefix` that affect this behavior as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a literal directory called `$PREFIX`, just prepend a `\` before the `$`, for `\$PREFIX`, then your tab completion will work. If you don't have a literal directory called `$PREFIX`, then autocomplete will not work, because it needs to expand `$PREFIX` in order to determine what values are valid for the autocompletion.

Comment: This is not what I want. `$PREFIX` is not a literal directory but an environment variable `PREFIX` whose value is `/opt` which I want to use in path completion. However, I don't want it to be expanded to `/opt` by the shell during completion.

Comment: The I amend my answer to "No. There is no way to suppress expansion of any type of variable during auto-completion."